# Disable italic syntax highlighting in VS Code

Tags: javascript, syntax, visual-studio-code

Some words (`function`, `if`, `else`, `return`, etc) are automatically formatted to italic is VS Code. How can I disable this behavior?

[image: spam]

Answer (score 43):

You can force VS to disable all your italics for your theme using the following user configurations:

```js
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": [
        "comment",
        "comment.block",
        "comment.block.documentation",
        "comment.line",
        "constant",
        "constant.character",
        "constant.character.escape",
        "constant.numeric",
        "constant.numeric.integer",
        "constant.numeric.float",
        "constant.numeric.hex",
        "constant.numeric.octal",
        "constant.other",
        "constant.regexp",
        "constant.rgb-value",
        "emphasis",
        "entity",
        "entity.name",
        "entity.name.class",
        "entity.name.function",
        "entity.name.method",
        "entity.name.section",
        "entity.name.selector",
        "entity.name.tag",
        "entity.name.type",
        "entity.other",
        "entity.other.attribute-name",
        "entity.other.inherited-class",
        "invalid",
        "invalid.deprecated",
        "invalid.illegal",
        "keyword",
        "keyword.control",
        "keyword.operator",
        "keyword.operator.new",
        "keyword.operator.assignment",
        "keyword.operator.arithmetic",
        "keyword.operator.logical",
        "keyword.other",
        "markup",
        "markup.bold",
        "markup.changed",
        "markup.deleted",
        "markup.heading",
        "markup.inline.raw",
        "markup.inserted",
        "markup.italic",
        "markup.list",
        "markup.list.numbered",
        "markup.list.unnumbered",
        "markup.other",
        "markup.quote",
        "markup.raw",
        "markup.underline",
        "markup.underline.link",
        "meta",
        "meta.block",
        "meta.cast",
        "meta.class",
        "meta.function",
        "meta.function-call",
        "meta.preprocessor",
        "meta.return-type",
        "meta.selector",
        "meta.tag",
        "meta.type.annotation",
        "meta.type",
        "punctuation.definition.string.begin",
        "punctuation.definition.string.end",
        "punctuation.separator",
        "punctuation.separator.continuation",
        "punctuation.terminator",
        "storage",
        "storage.modifier",
        "storage.type",
        "string",
        "string.interpolated",
        "string.other",
        "string.quoted",
        "string.quoted.double",
        "string.quoted.other",
        "string.quoted.single",
        "string.quoted.triple",
        "string.regexp",
        "string.unquoted",
        "strong",
        "support",
        "support.class",
        "support.constant",
        "support.function",
        "support.other",
        "support.type",
        "support.type.property-name",
        "support.variable",
        "variable",
        "variable.language",
        "variable.name",
        "variable.other",
        "variable.other.readwrite",
        "variable.parameter"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Original source:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32579#issuecomment-341502559

Comment: please consider accepting an answer if you find any useful, thanks :)

Comment: Please if you copy-paste something from somewhere, link a reference to it. The exaclty-the-same code is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32579#issuecomment-341502559).

Comment: Sadly, it also wipes bold. I have settled for comment-related scopes only.

Answer (score 1):

You can add those configuration into your settings.json file:

```
...       
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": { 
            "[Material Monokai High Contrast]": {
                "textMateRules": [
                    {
                        "scope": "entity.name.function",
                        "settings": {
                            "foreground": "#9DFF00",
                            "fontStyle": ""
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        }
```

`[Material Monokai High Contrast]` : The theme you want modify.

You can try use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> as well to autocomplete and help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong theme! New theme changed it and it works just fine.