# How can I disable italics in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing some python script in VSCode, and I noticed that it's displaying function arguments text in italics

For example

[image]

I like the colour, but why is "key" written in italics? I searched all of VSCode settings and couldn't find it - maybe it's the Python extension that's doing this? But I couldn't find settings for that either

Comment: I ran this on my version, and this is your theme (Monokai).
I'm afraid there's no way to fix this except changing your theme... :/

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219768/disable-italic-syntax-highlighting-in-vs-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219768/disable-italic-syntax-highlighting-in-vs-code)
Yo, go check this one out.

Comment: As ForcX FPV pointed out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219768/disable-italic-syntax-highlighting-in-vs-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable italic syntax highlighting in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219768/disable-italic-syntax-highlighting-in-vs-code)

Comment: I believe an image is appropriate here, as it's the only way to show the italics within the function signature. @Rob

Comment: I'm not sure why @Rob deleted his comment, but he was basically telling me to write it in a code block instead of using a screenshot

Answer (score 18):

Until VSCode adds that setting, the workaround is to add this to the `settings.json`:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "comment",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

That setting manually uses `''` for the `font-style` on comments. Additional scopes may be required depending on where your theme uses italics.

Answer comes from this GitHub issue thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32579#issuecomment-813005373

Answer (score 9):

**Just add this to the settings.json**

https://gist.github.com/pauldan/f3dbb3e33ee00acc36ad28c9e1de1bf9

This will work on any theme ✅

Reference: [Reddit - Remove italic from VS Code theme](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/n1o9kh/wanting_to_remove_italics_from_my_vscode_theme/)

Comment: This works. Spent over an hour trying to find this. Thank you.

Comment: @silian-rail Your most welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using an extension for the theme in vscode. Then follow these steps.

- `Ctrl/cmd + shift + x` -> search extension eg `one dark pro`.

[image]

- Click the settings icon and select `Extension settings`.

[image]

- Toggle italics.

[image]

- Reload your window.

Comment: not every theme has settings, but your answer does apply to many themes ;)

Answer (score 6):

there is an issue open on Github with a workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32579#issuecomment-341502559

You can be more granular and narrow down the list of scopes if you know which one you want to change.
To get the list of scopes use "Developer: Inspect Editor tokens and scopes" from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+p)

[Screenshot of Textmate Scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpLRA.png)

Answer (score 1):

On the latest version of `VSCode`, it works on me when I set the `scope = ['keyword.control']` and `settings.fontStyle = ''`, instead of putting all configs in the scope that didnt related to your concerns

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
   "textMateRules": [
      {
         "scope": [
            "keyword.control",
         ],
         "settings": {
            "fontStyle": ""
         }
      }   
   ]
},
```

Answer (score -1):

its because the monokai theme's. change other theme (like the vscode default theme) should solve the problem