# I can't for the life of me disable italics for VS Code

Tags: json, visual-studio, italic

Okay, I'll keep it straight:

I don't know JSON files. I've tried copy pasting numerous online solutions directly into settings.json to disable italic font for VS Code. None of them ever worked.

Here's what I tried:

- [this comment on github addressing all scopes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32579#issuecomment-341502559)
- [this entire thread on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460427/how-can-i-disable-italics-in-vscode)

I use Fira Code Font and Tokyo Night Color Theme. Does this combination somehow make it impossible for me to deactivate italics? The only words bothering me are "if, else, in, for, while" etc...

Can someone shed some light on this programming noob? Am I doing something wrong? Is it just impossible?

Also, I've messed around so much that, when "Inspecting Editor Tokens and Scopes",  when I select a *for* this is what it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `settings.json`

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "comment",
                "punctuation.definition.comment",
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": ""
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't work, but it guided me towards the Tokyo Night extension (My Color Theme) where they have a similar code addressing this italic behavior directly!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this, in my case, was to paste this code I found on the extension page in VS Code into `settings.json`:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Tokyo Night]": { // or "[Tokyo Night Storm]"
            "textMateRules": [{
                "scope": [
                    "comment",
                    "meta.var.expr storage.type",
                    "keyword.control.flow",
                    "keyword.control.return",
                    "meta.directive.vue punctuation.separator.key-value.html",
                    "meta.directive.vue entity.other.attribute-name.html",
                    "tag.decorator.js entity.name.tag.js",
                    "tag.decorator.js punctuation.definition.tag.js",
                    "storage.modifier"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": ""
                }
            }]
        }
    },
```

To my understanding, this addressed my Color Theme directly, whereas other solutions didn't.